# access denied when viewing profiles of other users

Tags: panels, users

I am having a hard time finding out why non admins (and anonymous users) are having 
"access denied" errors when looking at Drupal-7 profiles of other users.

The "View user profiles" permission is checked.

My user's profile page is a panel, but the 'access denied' errors even if the profile is not a panel.

Any idea? Please help.

Additional Information:

Using a code inspired by Yuriy Babenko's answer, and filterning for uniqueness, I see the following pemissions are denied when user 163 views the profile of user 174 (goes to /user/174) :

`access administration menu`
`access administration pages`
`access all views`
`administer block classes`
`administer blocks`
`administer contexts`
`administer less`
`administer media`
`administer menu`
`administer user relationship`
`administer users`
`administer views`
`bypass node access`
`execute php code`
`view any private_notification content`
`view own unpublished content`
`view the administration theme`

I don't see anything related to user access...

The nice [Access Denied Backtrace](https://drupal.org/project/adb) module gives the following backtrace, but how to interpret it?

```
Array
(
    [ 2: drupal_deliver_page()] => Array
        (
            [file] => includes/common.inc:2564
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 
                )

        )

    [ 1: menu_execute_active_handler()] => Array
        (
            [file] => includes/menu.inc:532
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [ 0: main()] => Array
        (
            [file] => index.php:21
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [q] => user/174
                )

        )

)
```

HOTFIX: Adding the following code before line 820 of user.module temporarily solved the issue:

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && is_null(arg(2)) && 
    $string == 'administer users' ) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

But how do I find why the 'administer users' permission to view other user profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Impossible to say exactly without having access to your site, but something ON the profile page is causing this.

Do this (assuming you're on Drupal 7):

- Open /modules/user/user.module
- Scroll down to line 820 (which should be: `return isset($perm[$account->uid][$string]);`)
- Immediately above that line, add this code:

.

```
if (!isset($perm[$account->uid][$string])) {
  echo 'denied permission: ' . $string . '<br/>';
}
```

- Reload the page as a user that's getting Access Denied, and you'll get a printout of all permissions the current user got denied - one (or more) of them will be the culprit.

Don't forget to remove the code changes once you've found the issue.

Comment: Thanks Yoriy, I tried it and added the answers I got to the question. Yet I see no permission related to users ...

Comment: I've also added the output of the 'Access Denied Backtrace' module.

Answer (score 0):

This was a menu permission issue.

On my module's hook_menu_alter(), I printed the menu into the site's watchdog:

```
watchdog( 'fb_menu_alter', '<pre>'.print_r($items, true).'</pre>');
```

Looking at the results for the 'user' path, it was immediately clear that the access callback was old:

```
 [user/%user] => Array
    (
        [title] => My account
        [title callback] => user_page_title
        [title arguments] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [page callback] => user_view_page
        [page arguments] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [access callback] => privacypu_check_access
        [access arguments] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => profile
                [2] => access user profiles
            )

        [menu_name] => navigation
        [module] => user
    )
```

Disabling the privacypu_profile module resolved the issue.